# There is any simple way to forming handmade paper pulp?

Tags: wood, woodworking, steel

I want to know how can I make a form for forming handmade paper pulp for something like paper egg container. There is possible to make small hand press from for example wood/steel and pressing that pulp only by hand without special machines. Im thinking about something like that but the other shape not flat, maybe something like diamond shape. There is possible making something like paper egg container from only handmade paper pulp?

Comment: Do you want to make the pulp or just make an egg container? I would first shred the source material so it breaks down quicker.

Comment: I knowe some about making paper pulp from the paper garbage but I want to know simple way to shape that to make small egg container, something like that but using diy method https://youtu.be/CA9xBSb9NZI

Comment: Well, papier-maché ie laying small strips of paper is a simple method. Had lots of fun making dinosaurs with kids as they grew up.

Comment: the handmade paper from old newspapers will save shape if the press squeezes it with the right strength and time and then it dries?

Comment: What press? Not mentioned in your original question... And "handmade"...

Comment: There is also an [Arts and Crafts SE](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to make a mold. Materials:

1. Egg container
2. Plaster of Paris
3. Vaseline
4. Small box that allows a couple of inches of space on all sides

   Take a egg container, Vaseline the outside lightly of the egg container, use mixed cement or plaster of Paris (my preferred material), pour half of the plaster in the box, press the egg carton into the plaster and let dry (you might need to weight the egg container so it doesn’t float out of the plaster). Now, you have the bottom half of your mold, Vaseline the inside of the egg carton lightly and the top of the plaster, pour the plaster into the box making sure to have a couple of inches of thickness, and let dry.

You now have your molds. Make your paper pulp (drier is better) pour in the mold and clamp the other mold into it gently and let it dry (probably a day or two until you can separate them.

Comment: Wow, perfect answer! I'm gonna try this